# Symfony2 pass option to abstract FormType

Tags: php, symfony

I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. I read quite some answers here on SO but I couldn't get it running.

My controller contains

```
$series = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DemoDemoBundle:Series')->createQueryBuilder('series')
    ->where('series.type = 1')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
$magazine = new Magazine();
$content = array(
    'series' => $series
);

$form = $this->createForm(new MagazineType($this->get('translator'), $content), $magazine);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

I would like to pass the variable `$content` to the form so that `'series'` can be used in some selectboxes. `MagazineType` extends `PublicationType`. The same goes for the underlying entities. Here's how `MagazineType` looks:

```
class MagazineType extends PublicationType
{
    function __construct($translator, array $series = null)
    {


 parent::__construct($translator, $series); //$series);
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // TODO: Refactor constant out
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options)
//            ->add('dateSubmitted')
//            ->add('userSubmitted')
//            ->add('file')
        ->add('issueNumber')
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'data_class' => 'Demo\DemoBundle\Entity\Magazine',
            'series' => $this->translator->trans('addPublication.noSeries')
        )
    );
}
```

and `PublicationType`

```
class PublicationType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $series, $translator;
    public function __construct($translator, $series)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->series = $series;
    }
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                    'label' => $this->translator->trans('addPublication.name')
                ))
    //            ->add('dateSubmitted')
    //            ->add('userSubmitted')
    //            ->add('file')
            ->add('series', 'choice', $this->series);//$formOptions['series']);
        ;
        return $builder;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Demo\DemoBundle\Entity\Publication',
                'series' => $this->translator->trans('addPublication.noSeries')
        ));
    }
```

Maybe I'm accessing the series variable the wrong way, but I'm not even getting any further than constructing MagazineType (option `series` not allowed) even though I've set it in DefaultOptions as stated on http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html#configure-allowed-types. I'm probably missing something here though similar questions, since I'm stuck on this the entire day.

Thx for any help!

Comment: at first... i don't see method **getName** in your FormType Classes, did you set them

Comment: @zavalit yep, I just didn't post it, but it's a simple getter.

Comment: i honestly don't know why do you need to extend your FormType twice, but what i see is in **->add('series', 'choice', $this->series)** it should be **->add('series', 'choice', array('data'=>$this->series)**

Comment: @zavalit Oh thank you! This brings me alittle bit further. Though **->add('series', 'choice', array('data'=>$this->series)** gives me an error. **->add('series', 'choice', array('choices'=>$this->series)** behaves really weird (prints me copyright notes of my css in the selection), but I thought that's how I needed to do it? What do I need to do to get the OptionsResolver actually setting an empty series index?